# Matlab - importing ascii data

Tags: matlab

I ve got an ascii file and im trying to import it to matlab in order to make some plots. Is there any way of importing those data, even tho they contain , (comma) rather than . (dot)?

```
00:00:00,000;-2,14;
00:00:00,001;-1,80;
```

Well the first column which I want to create is referred to the time and its corresponding to 00:00:00,001; 00:00:00,002; etc.
The second column should be the amplitude of the sample i.e. -2,14; -1,80 etc.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to import?  Which quantities for each row?  It's very unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Update your question with this new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup.  First use [`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) so that you can read each row of your text file as a cell in a cell array.  After, to allow for the processing of your times to be performed in MATLAB, you'll need to replace each `,` character with a `.`.  This will allow you to use MATLAB's commands for date and time processing.  Specifically, use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to help you do this.  Regular expressions help you find patterns in strings.  We can use these patterns to help extract out the data you need.  Use [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to replace all `,` characters with a `.`.

For the purposes of this answer, the example data that I'm going to be using is:

```
00:00:00,000;-2,14;
00:00:00,001;-1,80;
00:00:00,002;-0,80;
00:00:00,003;2,40;
00:00:00,004;3,78;
```

Therefore, assuming that your data is stored in a text file called `data.txt`, do:

```
%// Load in each row as a cell array
A = importdata('data.txt');

%// Each row has , replaced with .
Arep = regexprep(A, ',', '\.');
```

Now, what we can do is split up all of the quantities by using `;` as the delimiter.  We can use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to help us split up the quantities.  We can further decompose the data by:

```
Arep_decomp = regexp(Arep, '[^;]+', 'match');
```

The first parameter is the cell array that contains each of our rows in the text file (with the commas converted to periods).  The second parameter is a pattern that specifies what exactly you're trying to look for in each string in the cell array.  `[^;]+` means that you want to find all strings that consist of a bunch of characters **excluding** until we hit a semi-colon.  Once we hit the semi-colon, we stop.  `'match'` means that you want to retrieve the actual strings which will be stored as cell arrays.

The result after the above line's execution gives:

```
Arep_decomp{1}{1} =

00:00:00.000


Arep_decomp{1}{2} =

-2.14


Arep_decomp{2}{1} =

00:00:00.001


Arep_decomp{2}{2} =

-1.80


Arep_decomp{3}{1} =

00:00:00.002


Arep_decomp{3}{2} =

-0.80


Arep_decomp{4}{1} =

00:00:00.003


Arep_decomp{4}{2} =

2.40


Arep_decomp{5}{1} =

00:00:00.004


Arep_decomp{5}{2} =

3.78
```

You can see that the output cell array, `Arep_decomp` is a 5 element cell array, where each cell is a **nested** 2 element cell array, where the first element is the time, and the second element is the magnitude.   Note that these are **all strings**.

What you can do now is create two numeric arrays that will convert these quantities into numeric representations.  Specifically, the time format that you have looks like the form:

```
HH:MM:SS.FFF
```

`H` is for hours, `M` is for minutes, `S` is for seconds and `F` is for microseconds.  Use [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to allow you to convert these time representations into actual date numbers.  You would do this so that you can plot these on a graph, but then you perhaps want to display these times on the plot as well.  That can easily be done by manipulating some plot functions.  Nevertheless, use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) so that we can extract out the time strings as a separate array so we can use this for plotting later, and also use this to convert the time strings into date numbers via `datenum`, and convert the magnitude numbers into actual numbers.

Therefore:

```
datestr = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, Arep_decomp, 'uni', 0);
datenums = cellfun(@(x) datenum(x, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF'), datestr);
mags = cellfun(@(x) str2double(x{2}), Arep_decomp);
```

The first line of code extracts out each of the time strings as a single cell array - the `uni=0` flag is important to do this.  Next, we convert each time string into a date number, and we convert the magnitude strings into physical numbers by [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html).

Now, all you have to do is plot the data.  That can be done by:

```
plot(datenums, mags); 
set(gca, 'XTick', datenums);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', datestr);
```

The above code plots the data where the date numbers are on the horizontal axis, the magnitude numbers are on the vertical axis, but we will probably want to rename the horizontal axis to be those time strings that you wanted.  Therefore, we use to calls to [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) to ensure that the only ticks that are visible are from the date numbers themselves, and we relabel the date numbers so that they are the string representations of the times themselves.

Once we run the above code, we get:

[image]

Because the time step in between times is so small, it may clutter the horizontal axis as the labels are long, yet the interval is short.  Therefore, you may consider only displaying times at a certain interval and you can do that by doing something like:

```
step_size = 5;
plot(datenums, mags); 
set(gca, 'XTick', datenums(1:step_size:end));
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', datestr(1:step_size:end));
```

`step_size` controls how many ticks and labels appear in succession.  Obviously, you need to make sure that `step_size` is smaller than the total number of points in your data.

---

For your copying and pasting pleasure, this is what the full code I wrote looks like:

```
%// Load in each row as a cell array
A = importdata('data.txt');

%// Each row has , replaced with .
Arep = regexprep(A, ',', '\.');

Arep_decomp = regexp(Arep, '[^;]+', 'match');

datestr = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, Arep_decomp, 'uni', 0);
datenums = cellfun(@(x) datenum(x, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF'), datestr);
mags = cellfun(@(x) str2double(x{2}), Arep_decomp);

step_size = 1;
%step_size = 5;
plot(datenums, mags); 
set(gca, 'XTick', datenums(1:step_size:end));
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', datestr(1:step_size:end));
```

Comment: @rearyeng
What a descent reply. Unfortunately i still got an error:
Matlabs output:  
Error using datenum (line 179)  
DATENUM failed.  
  
Error in @(x)datenum(x,'HH:MM:SS.FFF')  
  
  
Error in asd_01_fixed (line 12)  
datenums = cellfun(@(x) datenum(x, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF'), datestr);  

Caused by:  
    Error using dtstr2dtnummx  
    Failed on converting date string to date number.

Comment: Make sure your text file conforms to the format that I have above.  I basically went with your model in your question.  If that isn't the format, then the code will not work.  Can you show me a sample of what your text file looks like?  See my example at the beginning of this post.  Does my text file and your text file match?  Remember, I only give code that **works**, provided that you **follow** the same input format I gave for the text file.  If it isn't, then I'm not responsible.

Comment: Its exactly what you have figured out on your own (i.e. HH:MM:SS.FFF) Everything goes smooth till the line datenums = cellfun(@(x) datenum(x, 'HH:MM:SS.FFF'), datestr); it seems something is wrong with datenum function.

Comment: @rearyeng heres the output of my file

Measurement time[hh:mm:ss];Write 0 [V];
00:00:00,000;-2,14;
00:00:00,001;-1,80;
00:00:00,002;-1,44;
00:00:00,003;-1,07;
00:00:00,004;-0,69;
00:00:00,005;-0,30;
00:00:00,006;0,08;
00:00:00,007;0,47;
00:00:00,008;0,85;
00:00:00,009;1,22;
00:00:00,010;1,59;
00:00:00,011;1,94;
00:00:00,012;2,27;
00:00:00,013;2,59;
00:00:00,014;2,88;
00:00:00,015;3,15;

Comment: You didn't tell me there was stuff at the beginning of your file. You can either delete those from the file or skip the first cell in the cell array.

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting my answer if I helped you. You can do that by going to the top of my post and clicking on the checkmark icon underneath the up and down arrows to the left. Good luck!

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could help me once more. I want to import a certain amount of lines, lets say the first 1k measurements. Is that possible through matlab or i should consider crafting my files one by one?

Comment: You can. I'd make a new question though. I consider this question you asked here solved.

Comment: Im pretty new here, so i aint know exactly how to use the sof. Moreover i have another file i need to read which is in the format Frequency;Write 0 [V];
0,00;0,31;
3,91;0,71;
7,81;0,93;
11,72;1,98; Do u think i should post a new question?

Comment: @sayidjetzenden - I'd say so.  That file is in a different format that requires a different answer.